# Nginx not proxying websockets properly

Tags: nginx, socket

Using the development version of nginx (1.3.12). In my relevant file under sites-enabled:

```
upstream twisted {
    server 127.0.0.1:8088;
}

server {  

    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4  

    server_name  *.clurn.co.uk clurn.co.uk;  

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/clurn.co.uk.access.log;  

    location / {  
            root   /var/www/clurn.co.uk;  
            index  index.html index.htm;  

    }  

    location /websocket {  
            proxy_pass http://twisted;  
            proxy_http_version 1.1;  
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;  
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";  
    }  

    location /websocket/server {  
            deny all;  
    }  

    [...snip...]
}
```

Only difference from [the example on nginx's site](http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/changeset/5073/nginx) is the capital u on upgrade, which seemed to be necessary for the Autobahn and/or [txWS](https://github.com/MostAwesomeDude/txWS) instances to recognise the websockets correctly (I can't remember which one it was atm).

Now, if I access the websockets via `127.0.0.1:8088` on the server, then it appears to work, but if I access it via `127.0.0.1/websockets` it doesn't, so there has to be something wrong with the marshalling of the packets via nginx.

If I run `netcat -l -p 8088` instead of the Twisted websocket backend, I can see that the requests are identical if accessed via nginx or directly (originally they weren't, but changing the "upgrade" to "Upgrade" made the header line `Connection: Upgrade` the same), so this part is proxying correctly.

However, if I telnet into `127.0.0.1:8088` and `127.0.0.1/websocket`, copying and pasting the correct request, I get a response with the direct `127.0.0.1:8088`, and do not with the `127.0.0.1/websocket`. What am I doing wrong, and how can I set it up to allow websockets on both sides?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 **/websockets** and 127.0.0.1:8088 **/** are different requests. Is it still working when you request 127.0.0.1:8088 **/websockets**?

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm getting pretty much the same behavior. I was able to successfully proxy through nginx with a websocket-only server (all the set_headers being at the root level of the server config), but get no responses otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is buffering. Set:

```
proxy_buffering off;
```

inside the websocket location config.

Comment: Unfortunately I no longer have the setup so can't check. But it sounds like if it solved your issue (if it were the same) then it may as well be marked as correct.

Comment: Another option is to disable buffering for just the upgrade with `proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;`, may need to ensure upgrade options set         `proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;` and `proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';`. Upside is this disables buffering for just the websocket connection if your websocket location is same as regular http/https location.